# SQL table.column not working when I use it with full join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT main.cname, main.email, das.a 
FROM main 
FULL JOIN das ON main.email = das.cname
```

And it returns the error :

> "unknown column main.cname in filed list".

while the column certainly exists:

```
SELECT main.cname 
FROM main
```

seems alright.

I tried using aliases but it just made it worse. I'm clueless

Comment: Please run describe on the two tables, and include the results in your question.

Comment: why you use full join? Just try to use  JOIN das ON main.email = das.cname

Comment: FULL JOIN isn't a thing in MySQL, so this is parsed as `SELECT main.cname, main.email, das.a 
FROM main AS full
JOIN das ON main.email = das.cname`

Comment: @coyeb60297 the sheer amount of hours I wasted trying...
problem solved thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As coyeb60297 has pointed out, MySQL doesn't do full outer joins so your query is:

```
SELECT main.cname, main.email, das.a 
FROM 
  main full
  JOIN das ON main.email = das.cname
```

and because `main` has been aliased as `full`, you can't say `main.cname` because `main` is not a thing

This would work:

```
SELECT full.cname, full.email, das.a 
FROM 
  main full
  JOIN das ON full.email = das.cname
```

.. but it isn't a full join (it just better explains the point above).

Consider instead something like:

```
SELECT main.cname, main.email, das.a 
FROM 
  main 
  LEFT JOIN das ON main.email = das.cname 
UNION
SELECT main.cname, das.email, das.a 
FROM 
  main 
  RIGHT JOIN das ON main.email = das.cname
```

If you face performance issues with the full join consider:

1. do you really need it?
2. MatBailie's suggestion to union on only those rows the left join lacks: `(a LEFT JOIN b) UNION ALL (a RIGHT JOIN b WHERE a.id IS NULL)`

Comment: `(a LEFT JOIN b) UNION (a RIGHT JOIN b)` can be particularly slow due to the elimination of duplicates?  Wouldn't `(a LEFT JOIN b) UNION ALL (a RIGHT JOIN b WHERE a.id IS NULL)` be significantly faster?

Comment: Works for me. Advice incorporated, thanks Mat